# Undefined error using javascript objects

Tags: javascript, dom, inner-classes, javascript-objects

I am newbie to javascript objects and I have a problem. I am trying to make an image gallery but I keep getting an error that this.current, this.size & this.initial are undefined, and therefore, the script cannot work. Please help me resolve this error. the following is the full script.

```
function gallery()
{
    this.image = new Array(10);
    this.initial = 1;   
    this.current = 0;
    this.size = 10;
    this.frame_height = 400;
    this.frame_width = 600;
    this.initialize=function()
    {
        if(document.images)
        {
            var count = 1;
            for(count=1;count<=this.size;count++)
            {
               this.image[count] = new Image();
               this.image[count].src = 'images/'+count+'.jpg';                 
            }
        }

    divImg.id = "divImg";   
    divImg.setAttribute("Width",this.frame_width);
    divImg.setAttribute("align","center");   
    divImg.setAttribute("margin","0px auto"); 


    divBtn.id = "divBtn";    
    divBtn.setAttribute("align","center");  
    divBtn.setAttribute("backgroung-color","Black"); 
    divBtn.setAttribute("color","White"); 
    divBtn.style.margin = "0px auto";   
    divBtn.className ="btn";

    pictureFrame.src = this.image[this.initial].src;
    pictureFrame.setAttribute('Width',this.frame_width);
    pictureFrame.setAttribute('Height',this.frame_height);
    pictureFrame.name = 'img';

    btnNext.innerHTML='NEXT';
    btnPrevious.innerHTML='PREVIOUS';
    btnLast.innerHTML='LAST';
    btnFirst.innerHTML='FIRST';

    btnFirst.onclick=this.first;
    btnLast.onclick=this.last;
    btnPrevious.onclick=this.previous;
    btnNext.onclick=this.next;  

    myForm.appendChild(pictureFrame);
    divImg.appendChild(myForm);

    divBtn.appendChild(btnFirst);
    divBtn.appendChild(btnPrevious);
    divBtn.appendChild(btnNext);
    divBtn.appendChild(btnLast);

    pageBody.appendChild(divImg);
    pageBody.appendChild(divBtn);
    headerTag.appendChild(pageBody);
}

this.next=function()
{
    alert(this.size);
    alert(this.current);
    if (this.current < this.size) 
    {
        this.current +=1;
        pictureFrame.src = this.image[this.current].src;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("This is the last image");
    }
}   
this.previous=function()
{
    alert(this.current);
    alert(this.initial);
    if (this.current > this.initial) 
    {
        this.current = this.current-1;
        pictureFrame.src = this.image[this.current].src;
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("This is the first image");
    }

}
this.first=function()
{
    this.current=this.initial;
    pictureFrame.src = this.image[this.current].src;
}
this.last=function()
{
    alert(this.size);
    this.current=this.size;
    pictureFrame.src = this.image[this.current].src;
}

};

var divImg= document.createElement('div');
var divBtn = document.createElement('div');
var btnFirst= document.createElement('button');
var btnNext= document.createElement('button');
var btnPrevious= document.createElement('button');
var btnLast= document.createElement('button');
var divTop = document.createElement('div');
var headerTag = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var pageBody = document.createElement('body');
var myForm=document.createElement("form");
var pictureFrame = document.createElement('img');


var pics=new gallery();
window.onload=pics.initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're expierencing an *out of scope* failure which is very common to people who are new to ECMAscript.

Every function has it's own *execution context* and each context in ECMA-/Javascript has its own `this` context variable. To avoid this, the most common way is to store a reference to the "outer" `this` context-variable in a local variable:

```
function gallery()
{
    this.image = new Array(10);
    this.initial = 1;   
    this.current = 0;
    this.size = 10;
    this.frame_height = 400;
    this.frame_width = 600;

    var self = this;

    //...

    this.initialize=function()
    {
        if(document.images)
        {
            var count = 1;
            for(count=1;count<=self.size;count++)
            {
               self.image[count] = new Image();
               self.image[count].src = 'images/'+count+'.jpg';                 
            }
        }
    // ...
```

This will work in like every Javascript environment. In the meantime, there are "better" (other) ways to avoid this problem in ECMA. For instance, ECMAscript Edition 5 introduces the `.bind()` method which let you "bind" the reference from the `this context variable` to an object of your choice. Lots of javascript frameworks offer a pretty similar way of binding `this` to an object, even Javascript itself lets you do it with a little effort.

Answer (score 1):

What jAndy said is correct, when the `window` object calls `pics.initialise`, `this` refers to `window` (`this` refers to the caller of the function, unless the function is anonymous).

However there is a simpler solution that you may prefer:

Instead of

```
var pics = new gallery();
window.onload = pics.initialize;
```

You can do:

```
var pics = new gallery();
window.onload = function() {
    pics.initialize();
};
```

Because it is wrapped in an anonymous function, `this` will refer to the `gallery` instance, instead of `window`.

jAndy's suggestions are definitely more robust, but may be a bit difficult for someone still grappling with Javascript.